# "Social Engineering" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

The meaning of "social engineering" I am looking for is the one related to information security, as in the [Wikipedia article on social engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)).

I could not find anything at all, no clue anywhere. What comes up is the meaning related to social science: `socia inĝenierado`, but there is no indication that this expression applies to information security.

I even try to look it up from the French angle: ["piratage psychologique"](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8349717) as defined by the Office québécois de la langue française (2007),
but I cannot possibly think that it translates to `psikologia hakado`.

Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Social" in this context refers to psyche (or adjective psychic) as you found out with help of French. If one reads the Wikipedia article, one realises, that it's more a question of manipulating minds rather than mining ore, building and maintaining machines or other engineering activities. So I would say *psika manipulado*.

Addendum 2021-01-07

I like Eduardo's suggestion of *menso* for the object of the manipulation, so I revise my answer to *mensa manipulado*. And if you need to express that it concerns technics for or study of the manipulation:

- *tekniko por mensa manipulado*
- *studo de mensa manipulado*

and so on

Answer (score 2):

I like Juha's answer, but would like to propose another one. Given the meaning of *trompi* (Intence erarigi por sia profito aŭ pro nura malico) and *menso* (Tiu parto de vivanta estaĵo, kiu pritraktas informojn, konscie aŭ ne) I propose:

```
mensotrompa tekniko
```

I cannot explain why, but I find *mens* more adequate than *psik* for this.

Comment: Indeed _menso_ sounds good in the given context so how about _mensa manipulado_?

Comment: _mensa manipulado_ bonas. Depende de la situacio oni povus aldoni _tekniko_ aŭ _scienco_ aŭ _fako_ por pli bone priskribi la amplekson de la afero (kaj la fakton ke studoj, scienco kaj esploroj subtenas ĝin).